# How can I program an “Exit” menu item in the System Tray in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem, exit, system-tray

When I right click on the system tray icon of my application I want to display an "exit" option on the menu and when I click this option I want the program to exit. How can I achieve this?

Comment: That is an OS functionality, not application specific.

Comment: Do you absolutely mean the task bar or are you talking about the system tray? In either case your question is a little too broad to be useful.

Comment: Exactly , I mean  System tray  .Sorry

Comment: You want [NotifyIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.contextmenu.aspx). I'm sure there must be a good dupe target for this question but I can't find one...

Comment: I found the solution ,thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have an event, let's say double click to close the application. So when user double-clicks the icon in System tray, the application will exit. You can also build the tray menu and have the "Exit" as an option.

```
System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
    notifyIcon.DoubleClick += notifyIcon_DoubleClick;
    notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("MyIcon.ico");
    notifyIcon.Visible = true;
}

void notifyIcon_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    // OR
    // Environment.Exit(0)
}
```

Comment: it didn't work ,I need a context menu in systray with "Exit" option .
Thanks @Sunil

Comment: To create Context menu option you can follow this [example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/01b6f20c-d4fb-4956-a3f6-d5e5d91bd239/wpf-menu-for-system-tray-icon?forum=wpf)

Comment: I found the solution ,thanks guys :)

Comment: That's great! You can add as answer.